# How to Add json to list

Tags: android

private static final List VIDEO_LIST;
    static {

```
  List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 1", "Y_UmWdcTrrc"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 2", "1KhZKNZO8mQ"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 3", "VH3DW9bPTTA"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 4", "re0VRK6ouwI"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 5", "blB_X38YSxQ"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 6", "Bu927_ul_X0"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Titel 7", "3I24bSteJpw"));
  VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic], to increase your chance of getting answers to your questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please elaborate a bit what do you want to achieve? Do you want to map a JSON to collection (for example the JSON below)? Any object mapper will be able to do so as long as while unmarshalling you have provided the correct TypeReference:

```
{
  "VideoEntries": [{
    "title": "Title 1",
    "key": "Y_UmWdcTrrc"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 2",
    "key": "1KhZKNZO8mQ"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 3",
    "key": "VH3DW9bPTTA"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 4",
    "key": "re0VRK6ouwI"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 5",
    "key": "blB_X38YSxQ"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 6",
    "key": "Bu927_ul_X0"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 7",
    "key": "3I24bSteJpw"
  }]
}
```